# Find unique line in two different files based on specific field

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I need to compare two txt files containing several lines and create a third txt file with only lines that are unique to file 1.
An example of file 1 is the following:

```
../../A/folder/fname.gz | -12.36 | A:BCD:123:A, D:DFR:241:AZ1 
../../A/folder/fname2.gz | -4.56 | B:ABC:456:C | G:RFT:265:T
```

which goes on for thousands of lines, while an example of file 2 could be:

```
../../B/folder2/fname.gz | -7.65 | C:ABC:425:A
../../B/folder2/fname3.gz | -12.31 | A:BCD:758:D
```

I need to get all the lines from file 1 that are unique based on first field (for example `../../folder/fname2.gz` in the example). Note that `folder` can be different, but `fnameX.gz` should be unique. Both `folder` and `fname` contains `-` and/or `_`. The number of field in each line can be different.
The expected output for the example above should be:

```
../../A/folder/fname2.gz | -4.56 | B:ABC:456:C | G:RFT:265:T
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what should be  the relationship between the first and the second file.  You wrote "I need to get all the lines from file 1 which have a unique first field". Do you mean, that don't exist in file 2? In the example you provided, can you add the expected output?

Comment: @ I edited the question and added the expected output for the example. I am not native English speaker, so I apologize if I am not clear. As you suggested, I need to get all the lines from file 1 that are unique (i.e. not present in file 2), based on the first field `fname` (if the part containing `../../X/folderX/` is different in file 1 and file 2, but the `fname` is the same, it should not be counted).

Comment: Do you need only the first field (ie `../../A/folder/fname2.gz`), or the entire line that contains this field? Also, does the first field in each file is unique (ie, `../../B/folder2/fname.gz` can only appear once in the first file), or can the first field repeat inside each file?

Comment: @aviro it does not matter if the output contains only the first field or the entire line that contains the field. Let's say the entire line is ok. The first field can only appear once in file 1

Comment: What if file1 contained 2 or more occurrences of `fname.gz`, e.g. `/foo/fname.gz | whatever` and `/bar/fname.gz | whatever`, while file2 only contained 1 - should 1 of the rows from file1 be printed or not?

Comment: @Ed Morton each fname.gz occurres only once per file. Regarding the white space, they should be regular spaces (not tabs).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F ' *[|] *' '{ k=$1; sub(".*/", "", k) }
               !z { a[k]; next } !( k in a )' file2 z=1 file1
```

Read `file2` first, storing the filename part in an array. When reading `file1`, print a line if the filename does not exist in the array.

Comment: thanks @rowboat for your answer. However, this is not working, as it considers the full path of the fname, while I only need the fname (i.e. if the path is different, but the fname is the same, it should not be considered

Comment: @ginopino The `sub()` should take care of that. Does it work for you with the sample inputs provided in the question?

Comment: @ginopino I suspect that you're not using the commands in both answers correctly. Both answers work for me. You realize that you need to replace `file2` and `file1` with the actual names of **your** `file1` and `file2`, right?

Comment: @rowboat it is working with the sample inputs, but not with the actual files. So maybe there is something different in my files that I did not put in the sample inputs. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @aviro, yes I am replacing the file names in the commands. The problem should be in the actual files, that maybe are somewhat different from the samples I provided. I'll check and let you know

Comment: @rawboat here is how one of the lines in the actual files look like: `../../K131/TEST_0000001-results/OB3Z3759322998_RX1--4itj_prep--K131_config_lys.dlg.gz |  -8.42 | B:ILE:129:N,B:LYS:126:O,B:LYS:131:HZ1,B:LYS:131:HZ2,B:LYS:131:HZ3 | B:ILE:129:N,B:LYS:126:O,B:LYS:131:HZ1,B:LYS:131:HZ2,B:LYS:131:HZ3 | B:ILE:129:N,B:LYS:126:O,B:LYS:131:HZ1,B:LYS:131:HZ2,B:LYS:131:HZ3 | 1 | B:LYS:131:NZ`
I thought the example should have been enough, but maybe it was not. I edited again the question to include more details. Do you see something that could make your commands not working?

Comment: You're going to have to update the example in your question to include lines that the posted answers don't work for if you'd like help debugging to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

We may use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and a helper shell function, and assume that the filename in the first field of each file does not contain `|` characters and that the fields are otherwise delimited by `|` surrounded by optional blanks (spaces and/or tabs).

We start by defining a helper function, `sorter`, that extracts the filename from the first field of the input data and prefixes each line with this filename before sorting the data:

```bsh
sorter () {
    awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\|[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS='|' \
        '{ key=$1; sub(".*/","",key); print key, $0 }' |
    sort
}
```

Change `$0` to `$1` in the code above if you just want the pathname from the first field in the final output. Change it to `$2` to only get the second field, etc.

The data needs to be sorted on the filename since the `join` utility assumes its input is sorted on the join field.

The function reads from its standard input, and this is what it looks like if we just run the first file through it:

```bsh
$ sorter <file1
fname.gz|../../A/folder/fname.gz | -12.36 | A:BCD:123:A, D:DFR:241:AZ1
fname2.gz|../../A/folder/fname2.gz | -4.56 | B:ABC:456:C | G:RFT:265:T
```

Doing this on each input file and using `join` to join on the first field, we may ask `join` to only output the lines from the first file that can't be paired with any line in the second file using `join -v 1`:

```bsh
join -t '|' -v 1 <( sorter <file1 ) <( sorter <file2 ) | cut -d '|' -f 2-
```

At the end, the `cut` command removes the filename field that our `awk` command added on each line.

The result, given the data in the question, will be

```
../../A/folder/fname2.gz | -4.56 | B:ABC:456:C | G:RFT:265:T
```

With `$0` replaced by `$1` in the `awk` code, you'll get just

```
../../A/folder/fname2.gz
```

Comment: thank you @they for your reply. I tried to use your sorter function, but it give me no results. I noticed that there is an additional folder before the fname, so maybe is because of that. I edited the question. How should I change the sorted function?

Comment: @ginopino, please show the exact "sorter" line you ran and the output.

Comment: @ginopino You can change `$0` to `$1` in the `awk` code to only have the pathname in the final output. I added a note about this to the answer.

Comment: @ginopino You can add however many directories to the pathname in the first field that you want, both mine and rowboat's code will strip out the filename part of the pathname correctly and use that as a key for comparisons. Their code assumes that each `|` is flanked by possible spaces, while I allow tabs and/or spaces around each `|`.